# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.font.FontScaler

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

Using Apache poi to export data into an excel file which works just fine locally but when using the application on CentOS server the excel export throws the below exception. Any help finding the issue is appreciated.

- Using tomcat7 on both local and server.
- Not using any static initialization for poi.
- Checked server jre/lib to ensure rt.jar is there since that is where the class FontScaler is located.

Complete stack trace is below:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/APP] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.font.FontScaler] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.font.FontScaler
        at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.getScaler(TrueTypeFont.java:1251)
        at sun.font.FileFontStrike.<init>(FileFontStrike.java:177)
        at sun.font.FileFont.createStrike(FileFont.java:95)
        at sun.font.Font2D.getStrike(Font2D.java:344)
        at sun.font.Font2D.getStrike(Font2D.java:293)
        at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(CompositeStrike.java:77)
        at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:93)
        at sun.font.Font2D.getFontMetrics(Font2D.java:400)
        at java.awt.Font.defaultLineMetrics(Font.java:2175)
        at java.awt.Font.getLineMetrics(Font.java:2282)
        at java.awt.font.TextLayout.fastInit(TextLayout.java:589)
        at java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:529)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:208)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:337)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:320)
        at com.cmp.app.excel.CatalinaStoreExcelExporter.catalinaStoreExportToExcelFile(CatalinaStoreExcelExporter.java:63)
        at com.cmp.app.controller.CatalinaStoreDistributionController.catalinaStoreExportToExcel(CatalinaStoreDistributionController.java:111)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0):

Download `ae-awt.jar`and add it to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Your JRE tries to fall back to Sun's implementation. Check for UnsatisfiedLinkErrors, maybe some of your JRE's libraries are missing (*.dll or lib*.so).